# Angular unit test error: Unexpected value 'ObservableMedia' imported by the module 'DynamicTestModule'

Tags: angular, unit-testing

I have a fairly simple unit test file like so:

```
import { CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA } from '@angular/core';
import { async, ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { Http, HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { MockBackend } from '@angular/http/testing';
import { MaterialModule } from '@angular/material';
import { MediaChange, ObservableMedia } from "@angular/flex-layout";
import { PageHeaderComponent } from './page-header.component';
import { UserService } from '../user.service';
import { PreloadService } from '../preload.service';

describe('PageHeaderComponent', () => {
    let component: PageHeaderComponent;
    let fixture: ComponentFixture<PageHeaderComponent>;

    beforeEach(() => {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            declarations: [PageHeaderComponent],
            providers: [
                {
                    provide: Http,
                    deps: [MockBackend]
                },
                PreloadService,
                UserService
            ],
            imports: [MaterialModule, ObservableMedia],
            schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA]
        });

        fixture = TestBed.createComponent(PageHeaderComponent);
        component = fixture.componentInstance;
    });

    it('should be created', () => {
        expect(component).toBeTruthy();
    });
});
```

It's testing a run-of-the-mill Angular CLI component that contains a subscription to watch breakpoints for element visibility:

```
constructor(public media: ObservableMedia) {
    // watch for changes in breakpoint
    media.asObservable()
        .subscribe((change: MediaChange) => {
            // update the header tooltip state
            if (change.mqAlias == 'xs') {
                this.showHeaderTooltip = false;
            }
            else {
                this.showHeaderTooltip = true;
            }
        });
}

ngOnInit() {
    // check breakpoint and set header tooltip state
    if (this.media.isActive('xs')) {
        this.showHeaderTooltip = false;
    } else {
        this.showHeaderTooltip = true;
    }
}
```

It throws this error:

> Error: Unexpected value 'ObservableMedia' imported by the module 'DynamicTestModule'. Please add a @NgModule annotation. in http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/polyfills.bundle.js (line 6972)
>           ZoneAwareError@http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/polyfills.bundle.js:6972:28
>           syntaxError@http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/vendor.bundle.js:14803:39
>           http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/vendor.bundle.js:28487:55
>           forEach@[native code]
>   
> ....

I've seen similar error reports in my research, but not for `ObservableMedia`. I've tried adding the imports to app.module.ts, but that had no effect. What's missing?

Comment: if you have other node_modules in your sub-directories this could be the reason, for example in a local shared project that you might have used yarn link. This is due a versioning mismatch, run time get confused with relationships between tscongif moduleResolution and combinations of newer Node and Angular-cli installs. Cut the long story short delete the extra node_modules if you have any

Comment: @UlugToprak, thanks for the suggestion. I did refresh node_modules earlier.

Comment: By refreshing do you mean you ran npm install again? because thats not gonna solve the issue. I am guessing you have changed Angular or Node version recently. if you didn't i will let my self out

Comment: I removed the node_modules directory and ran install, and there's only one directory. I don't use Yarn. Angular has been on 4.2.3 during the entire project. Node was updated at some point but doesn't seem to be related to this problem. Thanks again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you should use `FlexLayoutModule` instead of `ObservableMedia` because `ObservableMedia` is just base abstract class while you need to import angular module i.e class adorned with with `@NgModule` decorator

[Docs](https://github.com/angular/flex-layout/blob/master/src/lib/media-query/observable-media.ts#L22-L25)

Comment: Thanks. Strange that `{ MediaChange, ObservableMedia }` is required in the component itself, but doesn't work in the test file.